# Get [[VALUE]] or [[TAGNAME]]xxxx[[/TAGNAME]] with regex

Tags: c#, regex

I work with texts that have the following convention:

1. `[[PLACEHOLDERNAME]]` is a placeholder within the text which will replaced.
2. `[[VALUENAME]Text or Value[[/VALUENAME]]` is a Key/ Value pair which I need to read out from the text.

The key / value pairs (2.) I get with

```
Regex dataValueRE = new Regex(@"\[\[(?<datakey>.*\w)]\](?<datavalue>.*?)\[\[/\1\]\]", RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

but I have problems to get ONLY the placeholder (1.) with a different regex because this

```
\[\[(?<placeholder>.*\w)\]\]
```

will get the ones from 2. too.

Any hints are welcome!

Comment: What do you mean by *with a different regex*? What regex and what is the problem then? I understand it now, as if you needed `.*?` instead of `.*`.

Comment: A text contains many placeholders (1.) and key / value (2.) statements.

I need to extract them into separate lists or dictionaries. For 2. I use the above Regex and that works well.

But I can not get the placeholders (1.) seperately without catching the key / value statements (2.) again because they also start with `[[xxxx]]`.

Comment: I understand you know what you are talking about, but we do not see the problem the way you do. See [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide an [MCVE (minimal complete verifiable example)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: `2.` and your regex has unbalanced brackets. Typo?

Comment: Example:

This is a `[[PLACEHOLDERNAME_1]]`and this is a `[[DATANAME_1]]Key / Value pair[[/DATANAME_1]]` and here is another `[[PLACEHOLDERNAME_2]]` and here is another `[[DATANAME_2]]Key / Value pair[[/DATANAME_2]]`


I like to extract

`[[PLACEHOLDERNAME_1]]` and `[[PLACEHOLDERNAME_2]]`

into one list or dictionary and

`[[DATANAME_1]]Key / Value pair[[/DATANAME_1]]` and 
`[[DATANAME_2]]Key / Value pair[[/DATANAME_2]]`

into another one.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to add more details such as example. When you [edit] the question you can format the new text neatly. Adding big lumps of explanatory text in comments make it hard to understand what you want.

Comment: I think the problem with your regular expressions is the `.*` and `.*?` pieces. It may be better if they are replaced with `[^\[\]]*` and the non-greedy version. These attempt to allow a repeat of any character other than `[` and `]`.

Answer (score 0):

If I've correctly understood, you can use negative lookahead:

```
\[\[(?<placeholder>[^\]]*\w)\]\](?!.*\[\[/\1\]\])
```

then you may want to disallow the slash at the begin:

```
\[\[(?!/)(?<placeholder>[^\]]*\w)\]\](?!.*\[\[/\1\]\])
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/e31rg1/1)

Comment: The second one is what I was looking for:

    \[\[(?!/)(?<placeholder>[^\]]*\w)\]\](?!.*\[\[/\1\]\])

Thank you very much!